# synchronous call weather api and then display the information

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Purpose:**
>   onClick event trigger synchronous call to getWeather() then call display()

```
var position={} // object containing latitude and longitude

var getWeather = function(pos) {
$.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
    lat: pos.lat,
    lon: pos.lng,
    appid: "*****appid***"
}, showWeather, 'jsonp');

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(weather_data)
    });
};

var showWeather = function(data) {
    return weather_data;

};
function display(weather_info){
  console.log(weather_info);
}
```

These are the above two functions that I want to run synchronously using ***promise*** and in the respective order;

**Problem:**

When I used it in click function it does not not return the weather_data.

```
$("html").click(function() {      
    getWeather(position)
        .display(getWeather);

});
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

> showWeather callback function from $.getJSON is creating this trouble. I don't know where to return the promise();

Comment: We need to see the actual logic in `getWeather()`. I'm guessing you're not using the async pattern correctly, and are attempting to return data before the request completes instead of working with the promise from the request

Comment: does `weather_report` contain a function called `display` (that takes a function as argument)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can see the code here http://jsfiddle.net/vyELp/123/

Comment: @baao I made this display method! You can check the code at  jsfiddle.net/vyELp/123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it myself**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyELp/126/) of the correction

```
var getWeather = function(pos) {        

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var data_w={};
        $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
            lat: pos.lat,
            lon: pos.lng,
            appid: "*****appid****"
        }, function(data) { resolve(data)}, 'jsonp');

    });

};
```

This above lines speaks for themselves. I have made the whole API call a promise. That's how I solved it.

**If someone finds better way, please respond!**